# "Whose duty was" vs. "whose duty it was"

Tags: pronouns, dummy-it

I read the following sentence in the book *Word power made easy*:

> Charles C. Boycott was an English land agent whose difficult duty it was to collect high taxes from Irish farmers.

Is there a need for the *it* between *duty* and *was*?

Comment: ***whose difficult duty it was to x*** is the same as ***whose difficult duty was collecting x***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions are grammatical.  But perhaps slightly  different in emphasis?

> Charles C. Boycott was an English land agent whose difficult duty it was to collect high taxes from Irish farmers.

means

> Charles C. Boycott was an English land agent.  It was his difficult duty to collect high taxes from Irish farmers.

But

> Charles C. Boycott was an English land agent whose difficult duty was to collect high taxes from Irish farmers.

means

> Charles C. Boycott was an English land agent. His difficult duty was to collect high taxes from Irish farmers.

Both correct.

Comment: To me the difference between them is as follows: _A, whose duty was to do X_ implies that X formed either the entirety of A's duty or the overwhelming majority of it whereas _A, whose duty **it** was to do X_ implies that A had other duties and responsibilities as well as X.